# (Android) - how to trigger an alarm when user gets to a certain location?

Tags: android, triggers, location, alarm

I need to trigger an alarm when the user gets to a certain radius of co-ordinates. I am a newbie, please be as simple as possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is called a geofence, and the simplest way to set one up would be to use the `LocationClient` from the Play Services SDK. This technique is covered in [the Android developer documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/location/geofencing.html).

You can also [use "proximity alerts" with `LocationManager`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#addProximityAlert%28double,%20double,%20float,%20long,%20android.app.PendingIntent%29), avoiding the need for the Play Services Framework.